# Como agregar evenListener a mas de 1 input

Tags: javascript

tengo 2 inputs de tipo contraseña, me gustaria agregarles un visor, se que lo puedo hacer de esta manera.

```
$(".eye_icon").on('click',function() {
  if ($(".password").attr('type') === 'password') {
      $(".password").attr('type', 'text');
  } else {
      $(".password").attr('type', 'password');
  }
});
```

pero esto solo estaria funcionando para 1 solo, como podria hacer la distincion entre 1 visor y otro?

Comment: Eso deberia de funcionar para los dos.  Porque no agregas tu HTML

Comment: No me queda claro si quieres diferenciar entre un visor y otro, o como dice el titulo de la pregunta, agregar un eventListener a mas de un input.

Comment: Eso estaria funcionando para todos los elementos que tengan la clase `eye_icon`, que pueden ser uno o varios. Pon tu HTML tal como te han dicho para verlo mejor, gracias.